# Web Part List title not visible

Tags: list, web-part

I'm fairly new with sharepoint, but I need to handle some stuff and I'm now stuck with making visible the title of one list web part. 
Could anyone advise?
Thanks

Comment: is this an out of the box webpart or custom? what version of sharepoint are you using?

Answer (score 4):

Click on Site Settings->Edit Page. Select the list on the page and click Edit Web Part. In the Appearance section, provide the Title and select chrome type to Default.

Comment: Nadeem thank you so much. Your answer solved my issue.

Comment: @Roxana Please mark it as 'Answer'.